# Having trouble getting paths

Tags: php

I am trying to get the path of a directory which contains a PHP script. Let's name it **script.php**. It also contains included **log.php**.

**script.php:**

```
include_once __DIR__.'/../lib/log.php';
func();
```

**log.php:**

```
function func() {
   file_put_contents(__DIR__.'/log', 'Log file successfully created');
}
```

I execute **script.php** expecting the **log** file appear along with **script.php** but it doesn't happen. What happens instead is **log** file is being created in **lib** directory along with **log.php** file.
The only workaround I see here is to pass dir path to **log.php** through the function as an argument like this:

**script.php:**

```
include_once __DIR__.'/../lib/log.php';
func(__DIR__);
```

**log.php:**

```
function func($arg) {
   file_put_contents($arg.'/log', 'Log file successfully created');
}
```

Is it actually possible to get path to **script.php** through **log.php** without passing any arguments?
I just want to include the script, call a function and create new file along with script which contains include.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. PHP does not make any metadata available beyond that relating to the file it is currently executing within.

What you *can* do to make your file paths a bit easier to deal with is define a constant in your config or header file that defines the absolute path to the root of your application. Eg:

```
define('APPROOT', __DIR__);
```

Or:

```
define('APPROOT', __DIR__ . '/../myapp');
```

Then you can define paths in your app without trying to rely on where a script happens to live, eg:

```
$log_file = APPROOT . '/log/foo.log';
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I have another question: is there a way to make a PHP-wise global variable or constant? Somewhere in config file like php.ini or so.

Comment: Not that I know of. Why would you want that anyway?

Comment: I need to declare constant which will be available from everywhere without including anything.